# Problem with Beautifulsoup and csv (written data is lost)

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am **scraping** a web. Sometimes everything goes well and suddenly it stops working and ends the script without Traceback but when opening the file the data is cut (they are not complete).
I am working with Beautifulsoup and I save the data in a "csv" file. I have done several tests:

1. I print the soup table and the data is complete.
2. I took the for loops out of the with and printed the data on screen and it worked fine.

The problem is then due to the opening and writing of the csv.
This is part of the script:

```
url= 'http://www...'
r= requests.get(url,headers=header).content
soup=BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
tabla= soup.find(id='main_table').find('tbody')

with open('Est.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer= csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['Cont','Recup','Act']) #column names
    for fila in tabla.find_all('tr'): 
        nroCelda=0
        for celda in fila.find_all('td'):
            if nroCelda==1:
                cont=celda.text #and so on the rest of the variables
            nroCelda=+1
        writer.writerow([cont,recup,act])
```

I appreciate all the help and information you can provide.

Comment: You aren't incrementing `nroCelda` so it's always `0`. Where's `recup` , `act` defined? Can you share URL?

Comment: (1) what's the URL? It's difficult to reproduce your issue without it. (2) could it be that the OS is killing your process for some reason?

Comment: Sorry Andrej Kesely, I forgot to add the counter increment. That is included in my script and the problem is the same. I already edited.

Comment: Roy2012 the url is 'http://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/' I only put the code for a single column so as not to make it so long here

Comment: Neither recup not act are defined. What are they? (or what values are they supposed to contain)?

Comment: Also, there's no table with id 'main_table. Try to use tabla= soup.find(id='main_table_countries_today').find('tbody') instead.

Comment: Thanks Roy2012, I'm going to edit the script with the orginal parameters for a best evaluation.

Comment: I have already solved the problem. I don't know why the writer method won't let me write the variable "cont" first and then "recup". I inverted the variables and it ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll propose what I believe as a simpler solution: read the table using pandas and then write it to a csv using pandas:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# this is needed because of some issue pandas has with this specific page. 
text = re.sub(r'<.*?>', lambda g: g.group(0).upper(), res.content.decode("utf-8") )
dfs = pd.read_html(text)
dfs[0].to_csv("covid_19.csv")
```

This produces a csv file named "covid_19.csv".

Comment: Thanks Roy2012, I would like to know what happens with the code that I have implemented.